# Shader programming with ShaderLab and CG in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, cg

I am trying to **learn Shader programming using ShaderLab and CG in UNITY**. Is there any ***step by step FREE guide*** (videos/book/tutorial)available ?

Please **don't recommend me** **NVIDIA CG tutorials** (it is extremely descriptive and difficult to understand) and **unity official site** (there is no description only code)

I'm searching and learning Shader programming form last 3 days still didn't find any **good resource** and It is my observation/perception that **it is difficult to learn** although I have some experience and good understanding of C# and Javascript programming but facing much difficulty to learn it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any really good free resources, but I can recommend you this [really good book](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18128522-unity-shaders-and-effects-cookbook). It is worth buying it.

Comment: thanks for sharing a book I am going to read it. I will accept the answer if it  is work for me until + for u

Answer (score 0):

I've created a resource for getting started with shaders:

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Getting_Started_with_Shaders

Be warned, this was three years ago -- I have since moved away from Unity3D, and it doesn't look as though anyone else has updated it since.

As it is a wiki, I encourage anyone to update it with resources they have found useful.

Comment: thanks but link you mention i already have seen and it leads to me finally on unity3d official documentation. where i dont want to go as mention in question

Comment: You should read through that page more closely. Did you see the link to Jessy Catterwaul's videos?  Also, if you found that page, you could have linked it in the question -- remember, we are collectively building an information resource here.

Comment: i think video link have expired http://www.23video.com/closed showing this

Comment: I just checked and everything is just as I said. The link is there, and works.